# read more function with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to create a readmore function in codeigniter where the readmore link will be linked to a controller which would show all the data about that particular id....i am kind of confused on how to go about it... i tried...

```
<?php 
                    $research_detail_url = site_url()."/research/research_details";
                    //echo json_encode($research)
                    if($research)
                    {
                        foreach ($research as  $_research) {
                            $author = $_research->author;
                            $content = $_research->content;
                            $dsubmitted = $_research->dsubmitted;
                            echo "<div class='menu-collapse'> <h5>$author</h5>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            echo "<span class='support_text'>$content <span><br />";
                            echo "<span class='support_text'>$dsubmitted <span><br />";
                            echo "<a href='$research_detail_url' target='_blank' style='text-decoration:underline; color:#0088cc;'>
                            read more &raquo; </a>";
                            echo "</p> </div>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

but i seem not be getting any results...i need help...
and this is my controller function.....

```
public function research_details($id='')
    {
        if(!$id)
        {
            echo "Project Id required";
            return;
        }   


        $_result = $this->projects_model->get_project($id);
        if($_result)
        {// success in fetching data hurray

            $result['projects'] = $_result;
            $users_ids = $this->users_model->get_user_ids(); //return available user id's
            $groups_ids = $this->groups_model->get_group_ids(); //return available group id's

            //echo json_encode($users_ids);
            //echo json_encode($groups_ids);
            $group_record = $this->map_names_to_ids($users_ids , $groups_ids );
            $result['group_record'] = $group_record;




            //load the view
            $this->load->view('__includes__/header');
            $this->load->view('__includes__/boostrap_responsive');
            $this->load->view('projects/project_panel', $result);
            $this->load->view('__includes__/footer_scripts');
            $this->load->view('__includes__/wijmo_file_jquery');
            $this->load->view('__includes__/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            exit("An Error occured in fetching the requested project");
        }

    }
```

and this is my model.....

```
<?php

class research_model extends CI_Model {


    function add()
    {
        $this->db->insert('research',$_POST);
        if($this->db->_error_number())
        {
            return $this->db->_error_number();
        }
    }

    function update($article_id, $data_fields = NULL){
        if($data_fields == NULL)
        {
            $this->db->where("article_id =".$article_id);
            $this->db->update('research',$_POST);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->where("article_id =".$article_id);
            $this->db->update('research',$data_fields);
        }

        $is_error = $this->db->_error_number();
        if($is_error){
            echo $is_error;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    function delete($id){
        $this->db->where("article_id =".$id);
        return $this->db->delete('research');
    }

    //return the research with this id
    function get_research($id){
        $this->db->where("article_id =".$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('research');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        else
            echo $this->db->_error_message();
            return FALSE;
    }

    //return the available research in the table
    function get_research_all(){

        $query = $this->db->get('research');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $result[]   =   $row;
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }





}
```

and my entire controller.....

```
<?php
class Research extends Public_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('research_model');       
    }

    function index()
    {
        if($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {

            $result =   $this->research_model->get_research_all();
            $data   =   array(
                'main_content'  =>  'research/index',
                'research'          =>  $result
            );
            $this->load->view("loader", $data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('home');
        }

    }//END INDEX


    // public view
    function current()
    {
        $result = $this->research_model->get_research_all();
        $data =  array('research' => $result); 

        $this->load->view('__includes__/header');
        $this->load->view('__includes__/navbar');
        $this->load->view('research/current', $data);
        $this->load->view('__includes__/footer');

    }

    function add()
    {
        if($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {
            $this->load->view("loader",array('main_content'=>"research/add_research"));
        }
    }//END ADD

    function edit($id='')
    {
        if(! $id)
        {
            echo "research Id required";
            return;
        }
        $result =   $this->research_model->get_research($id);
        if( ! $result)
        {
            echo "Nothing to edit";
            return;
        }
        $result['main_content'] =   "research/add_research";
        $this->load->view("loader",$result);
    }//END EDIT

    function delete($id='')
    {
        if(! $id)
        {
            echo "Id required";
            return;
        }
        $this->research_model->delete($id);
        $this->get_research();
    }//END DELETE

    function submit($id='')
    {

        //validate form [perform validation server-side to make sure of fields]
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');       

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            //ajax data array
            $data   =   array(
                'server_validation'     =>  validation_errors()
            );
            echo str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($data));
        }
        else{

            if($id){
                $result     =   $this->research_model->update($id);
                $content    =   "article has been UPDATED successfully";

                //$retArr["content"] = $content;
                //echo json_encode($retArr);
            }
            else{
                $result     =   $this->research_model->add();
                $content    =   "article has been CREATED successfully";
                //$retArr["content"] = $content;
                //echo json_encode($retArr);
            }
            //if duplicate key
            if($result == 1062){
                //ajax data array
                $data   =   array();
                    $data['is_valid']   =   0;

                echo json_encode($data);
            }else{
                //ajax data array
                $data   =   array(
                    'is_valid'  =>  1,
                    'content'   =>  $content
                );
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
        }//end ELSE form valid
    }//END SUBMIT

    public function research_details($id='')
    {
        if(!$id)
        {
            echo "Project Id required";
            return;
        }   


        $_result = $this->research_model->get_research($id);
        if($_result)
        {// success in fetching data hurray

            $result['article'] = $_result;



            //load the view
            $this->load->view('__includes__/header');
            $this->load->view('__includes__/boostrap_responsive');
            $this->load->view('research/research_details', $Aresult);
            $this->load->view('__includes__/footer_scripts');
            $this->load->view('__includes__/wijmo_file_jquery');
            $this->load->view('__includes__/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            exit("An Error occured in fetching the requested project");
        }

    }//END EDIT

}
?>
```

my public controller

```
<?php 
abstract  class Public_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $about_data;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //Making This variable availale for the whole site
        $this->load->model('about_model');
        $this->load->model('captcha_model');
        //get your data
        $this->about_data = $this->about_model->get_abouts();   


    }
}
?>
```

Comment: in your `foreach` loop, you are forgetting to close you `span` tag. You need `</span>`

Comment: What happens when you click on the "read more" link? do you see any errors? does it redirect anywhere?

Comment: Also, how are you planning on passing the ID to the controller? so far, your view seems to build the link with no ID, so when it reaches your controller, you will always hit "Project Id required"

Comment: I would also include your model methods, so that we can see if that side is correctly coded

Comment: @CodeGodie i will add my model methods, and yes my view keeps on hitting the "Project Id required"

Comment: do you understand why its hitting "Project Id required"? You are not passing an ID. Do you know how to?

Comment: @CodeGodie no, i dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of problems:

1. In your view, you are not closing the `span` tags. You need
   `</span>`
2. In your view, you are creating the link, but you are not
   including an ID, which you need in your controller. What I mean by this is the following:

   First,you create this `$research_detail_url = site_url()."/research/research_details";`.

   Then `echo "<a href='$research_detail_url' target='_blank' style=''>read more</a>";`

   As you can see, your URL does not have an ID when created. What you should do is something like this: `$research_detail_url = site_url()."/research/research_details/31";` where `31` is a random ID. You need to come up with the right ID needed in order to pass it to your controller. Your controller is currently assigning a blank ID since none is being passed which is why you end up with a result of "Project Id required"

Comment: i did that and i put a specific id over there just to be sure and i got this     An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: research/research_details.php

Comment: well `<a href="" target="_blank">` is going to open a new page or tab on your browser. It will look for the "Research" controller class, then to the "research_details" controller method. if you have `An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file: research/research_details.php` that tells me that the controller is not being seen. Can you show your entire controller with its name in your code?

Comment: ok . I see your controller class is extending from a parent class named "Public_Controller" Can you also include that controller's code?

Comment: I think it would be easier for me to help you through Teamviewer. There are too many factors. Do you want to do that? let me know

Comment: gimme a min let me download and install it... i need all the help i can get